# Building Nuxt sitemap from multiple data sources

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js

I'm working with Nuxt in SSR mode and want to build out a dynamic sitemap for multiple routes/ data sets.

The issue I'm facing now is that the async/ await function only allows 'data' as the variable. The same function with 'post' as the variable leads to a "map function does not exist"

This is what's in my Nuxt.config.js file

```
  sitemap: {
    hostname: "https://example.com",
    routes: async () => {
      let { data } = await axios.get('https://api.example.com/api/v1/locations');
      data = data.data.map((loc) => `/locations/${loc.slug}`);
      console.log(data);

      let { posts } = await axios.get('https://cms.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
      posts = posts.map((post) => `/posts/${post.slug}`);
      console.log(posts);

      data.concat(posts);

      return data
    },
    path: '/sitemap.xml'
  }
```

The resulting output I'm looking for should be formatted like this:

```
[
  '/locations/location-one',
  '/locations/location-two',
  '/locations/location-three',
  '/posts/post-one',
  '/posts/post-two',
  '/posts/post-three',
]
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and it's occuring on this line:

```
posts = posts.map((post) => `/posts/${post.slug}`)
```

so it appears to me that it's not accepting 'posts' as a valid variable for its own await function.

That call works fine when the first call is commented out and 'data' is used instead of 'posts'

Comment: the "generate: false" option is no longer used by the module since v2. you can remove it to avoid warning.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed 'generate:false.' Still getting the same error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your destructured response is wrong:

replace:

```js
let { posts } = ...
```

by:

```
let { data: posts } = ...
```

Because Axios always returns a "data" attribute, so you just have to rename it as "posts".

Comment: This did the trick, I then used `let routes = [].concat(farms).concat(posts)` and `return routes`

Comment: here is the test sample https://www.inhinyeru.com/blog/implement-nuxt-dynamic-sitemaps-in-multiple-data-sources-1624734684

Answer (score 0):

Your array concatenation must be like that:

```js
data.concat(posts);
```

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

---

The `push()` method is only to push one item, but not an array of item.

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Much appreciated, I've edited the post. The primary question is why 'posts' (and specifically the map function on posts) is not recognized while 'data' would be, and how to deal with both since they cannot both be assigned as 'data'